# How to use phone number from my missing phone to re-activate a Viber account

Tags: viber-messenger

My phone was stolen and I'd like to reactivate the same number to a new device. Unfortunately Viber is sending the code to the lost number. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: The same question applies if someone changed their phone number. I changed my phone number, and now I can't access my viber account.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting the question, and no answers have been upvoted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no you can't. The only ways to activate are via SMS or a call to receive the activation code and both methods require your phone number because the code will be sent to it. You are no longer in possession of the number you won't be able to activate Viber.

Your only solution is to talk with your service provider if it is possible to get your lost number back (it is possible in some countries). The process involves proving that the Sim (lost number) was yours by providing the last numbers called, received, if you bought data, what was the amount, etc.